# Get date of monday and sunday this week

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the date of monday and sunday this week.

I got this atm, but it dosn't give the right result when i set the current date to the same monday.

```
DECLARE @date datetime
set @date = '2013-09-01 11:15:51'


    SELECT DATEADD(day,
                   -1 - (DATEPART(dw, CONVERT (date, @date)) + @@DATEFIRST -2) % 7,
                   CONVERT (date, @date)
           ) AS ThisModay, 
           DATEADD(day, 6, CONVERT (date, @date)) as NextSunday
```

when trying that i get 2013-08-25 as monday, but it should be 2013-09-01

How can  i do this ? , have current week as results at all time. (current date should always be same as or between the two results)

Comment: if the @date is half way through the week do you want the monday before and the sunday after the date?

Comment: Last time I checked, both 20130825 and 20130901 were Sundays. How is either the correct answer?

Comment: @RobWhite Yes. The Date should ALWAYS be between the two or equal.

Comment: @NiclasSchumacher my question was silly as I think you've already explained. But my solution and a few others should do the trick.

Comment: @RobWhite with your solution the result was off by 1 day, so it went to tuesday to monday. But after i replaced 2 with 1, i got the right result!
But, my question is now, why did yours work with 2, and mine with 1? Something about week start or ?

Comment: its probably related to what some others have said. Sunday on my system is weekday 1 and Monday 2, it might be yours has Monday as being 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my previous answer was wrong, heres the correction

```
DECLARE @date datetime
declare @wd int
set @date = '2013-09-06 11:15:51'

set @wd = case when datepart(weekday,@date)<2 then 7-datepart(weekday,@date) else     datepart(weekday,@date)-2 end

select DATEADD(day, -@wd,@date) As Monday,
                DATEADD(day, 6-@wd,@date) As Sunday
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()),7)
```

for sunday

```
     SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

for monday

since by default first day of week is monday starting from 0

Comment: this worked fine, but.. When i try with date = '2013-09-08 11:15:51', then i goes a week forward.. Which it should. :/

Answer (score 0):

Before your declare code:

```
    set @@DATEFIRST = 1
```

by default it's 7 , meaning the first of the week is Sunday . When you put it equals to 1 , the first day will be monday,

Comment: the syntax would be SET DATEFIRST 1;

Answer (score 0):

try following

Actually you dont need SET DATEFIRST but this is for precaution only

```
SET DATEFIRST 7;
DECLARE @date datetime
set @date = '2013-09-11 11:15:51'


    SELECT cast(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @date), 0) as DATE) AS ThisModay, 
           DATEADD(day, 6, CONVERT (date, @date)) as NextSunday
```

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
DECLARE @date datetime = '2013-08-31 11:15:51'
DECLARE @Monday INT = 2
DECLARE @NextSunday INT = 8

SELECT 
DATEADD(day, (@Monday - DATEPART(dw, @date)), @date) AS ThisMonday
, DATEADD(day, (@NextSunday - DATEPART(dw, @date)), @date) AS NextSunday
```

Here [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73755/13) for testing